# How do I reverse an AngularJS route from a Django template?

Tags: angularjs, django

I have a Django application with an AngularJS frontend.  The application sends notification emails, which it renders using Django templates.

```
ITEM: {{article.title}}
DATE: {{article.date}}
SOURCE: {{article.link}}

{{article.body}}
```

The issue is `article.link`.  The previous version of the application didn't use Angular, so it was simple to find the link.  In `urls.py` we had

```
url(r'article/(?P<article>\d+)/$', views.ArticleView.as_view(), name='show-article')
```

which meant that we could reverse a URL to a particular article with

```
django.core.urlresolvers.reverse('show-article', kwargs={'article':article_id})
```

Now, on the Angular-based revamp of the site, the display URL for an article looks like `/mysite/#/article/1234` and is determined by `routes.js`:

```
$routeProvider.when('/article/:articleId', { ... } )
```

Bottom line, I don't have a way to grab an AngularJS route from Python.  I could hard-code the all the routes from `routes.js` into something the backend sees, but it wouldn't be very DRY.  I could generate `routes.js` dynamically with Django, but right now none of our other JS source is touched by Django -- that doesn't seem very clean either.  Maybe I should continue to support the old-style URLs (`/article/1234`) as a redirect to the Angular-style URLs (`/#/article/1234`)?  That still requires logical duplication, I think.

Is there a better pattern I should be using here?

Answer (score 0):

Decoupling clients and servers is often a goal so duplication should not be considered a bad thing in this case. Depending on your needs however there are solutions which provide a reverse method which behaves like in Django. There is [django-js-reverse](https://github.com/ierror/django-js-reverse) and [django-angular](http://django-angular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reverse-urls.html#examples) for angular specificaly.

Comment: Please keep in mind, I'm not trying to reverse a Django URL in Angular (I found a question here about that but I lost the tab :( ), I'm trying to reverse an Angular route in Django.  `django-js-reverse` is for going the other way.  The same is true of the `django-angular` page you linked.  I want to find frontend routes from the server, not backend URLs from the client.